# Create a bat file from a bat file with "%date:/=%" as line in new bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

> I want to create a bat file(A.bat) from another bat file(AA.bat)

```
AA.bat
echo mkdir %date:/=%  > A.bat

A.bat
mkdir %date:/=%
```

> But when i execute AA.bat, A.bat is created but content is as below

```
mkdir 15-Apr-17
```

> How to get the content of A.bat as

```
 mkdir %date:/=%
```

Comment: To escape a single percent sign double it `echo mkdir %%date:/=%%  > A.bat`

Comment: As an alternative perhaps the following could be helpful: **AA.Bat** - `Call A.bat "%DATE:/=%"`; **A.bat** - `If Not Exist "%~1\" MD %1`.

Comment: @LotPings i tried echo mkdir %%date:/=%% > A.bat & it worked : )

Thank you : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mkdir %%date:/=%%

```
To escape a single percent sign double it echo mkdir %%date:/=%% > A.bat – LotPings
```